# Help remembering name of  hotel in near Łódź, Poland?

Tags: hotels, poland, identify-this

This summer I was in Poland. We drove around by car and visited several small villages. I some help to remember the name of the village and the hotel we stayed in.

I have only some very vague hints:

The village is very near to Lodz. We arrived late in the evening and in Łódź we couldn't find an accommodation. Every hotel, hostel, campsite etc. was full. So we left Łódź in the direction of Oświęcim (Auschwitz). We drove on the highway only a very short time. Then we turned right and arrived in a very small village. But nevertheless it was a relatively luxurious hotel that had a big park and looked relatively new. This hotel is run by a father and son. We didn't stay in this hotel but in another one that was in the next street. The owner of the first hotel recommend this one.

Our hotel was very cheap and had a private parking space. It was necessary to get a key from the reception to open the gate to the parking lot. Almost opponent to this hotel there is a very small store that sells some food. Neither the hotel personal nor the shop owner speaks English.

It was late in the evening and we hadn't anything to eat. So we drove back on the highway and turned in the direction to Oświęcim. After 2 or 3 minutes we saw a restaurant directly at the highway in form of a mill.

That's all I can remember. I would be very happy if someone can identify the village and the hotel.

Comment: Trivia time: Was your hotel dirt, smelly and a "disgrace to the human race" (Gerrys review)? if yes, then it must be "Hotel Babel" in Brzeszcze (http://www.booking.com/hotel/pl/babel.en.html) :)

Comment: This question seems too localized for me.

Comment: @iHaveacomputer no it isn't this hotel. Our was really not nice, but it was kind of okay.

Comment: @VMAtm I agree that it is maybe not the right place to ask such a question. Therefore I ask a related question on meta to discuss if such questions should be allowed. But normally, the community want's "localized" questions, and the questions shouldn't be too broad.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Where you say "opponent" do you mean "opposite" or "adjacent"? In English an opponent is somebody you're fighting or playing a sport or game against.

Comment: I think it's too localized the way you've worded it. If there is a way to ask it which shows how it benefits other travellers I would consider it on-topic. For instance as a useful last resort accommodation in a place that will usually have all rooms sold in the busy season.

Comment: Ok I'll rephrase it today. And yes it should be opposite or adjacent.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Well opposite and adjacent have different meanings, that's why I couldn't pick one. "Opposite" means for instance "on the other side of the raod" and "adjacent" means for instance "right next door".

Comment: Ah yes sorry. It's opposite ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to find a picture of the hotel. As you can see, the name is written on the house. It is called Zajazd Lesny. [Travellerspoint](http://www.travellerspoint.com/accommodation/de/11604-Zajazd-Lesny/) provides some more detailed information about the hotel.

[image]

Comment: Zajazd = Inn :)